# Calling API with HttpClient catch BadRequest

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I'd like to call a Web API in .NET 6 with `httpclient`. The code **works fine** when I return `OK(result)`, I get the right result. The problem is when I return a `BadRequest`, I'd like to have access to the properties EN, FR, NL. In the `HttpRequestException`, I just receive the message "`500 internal exception error`", not the properties EN, FR, NL.

How can I do to get these values ?

```
[HttpPost(nameof(Testing), Name = "Testing")]
public async Task<ActionResult<MyResponseDto>> Testing(ParameterDto parameter)
{
    var res = new MyResponseDto
    {
        //Few properties her
    };

    //return Ok(res);

    return BadRequest(new { FR = "My Error FR", NL = "My Error NL", EN = "My Error EN" });
}
```

I call web api from console application doe testing purpose with this code :

in program.cs

```
var result = await Api.Testing();

public static class Api
{
    public static async Task<string> Testing()
    {
        string response = await HttpRequests.Post(
            "/api/Testing",
            new { /*  few parameter here  */ });
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyResponseDto>(response);
    }
}

public static class MyHttpRequests
{
    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    private const string url = "myURL";
    
    public static async Task<string> Post(string entryPoint, Object dto)
    {
        string url = $"{url}{entryPoint}";

        string dto = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto);

        HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(dto, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        try
        {
            using(HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, httpContent))
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                return responseBody;
            }
        }
        catch(HttpRequestException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Message :{e.Message} ");
        }

        return await Task.FromResult(string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: `BadRequest` means that you should receive 400 as status code not 500. Please check the server's logs to determine what went wrong on the server during the processing of your request.

Answer (score 0):

This line is throwing the exception:

```
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

Without it, you would continue to return the response body which will contain a json representation of your error variables.

So instead of throwing an exception like this, you can manually check the response status code and parse the json. EG:

```
public static async Task<string> Post(string entryPoint, Object dto)
{
    string url = $"{url}{entryPoint}";

    string dto = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto);

    HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(dto, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    using(HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, httpContent))
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            return responseBody;

        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {responseBody}");

    }

    return await Task.FromResult(string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: With your changes I have excpetion no more but I don't get the FR, EN and NL value just an '500 internal server" in the responseBody

Comment: sounds like your server code is not getting to the point of returning the 400 BadRequest object and has instead encountered an exception beforehand and returned 500.

Comment: It's strange when I return Ok(result) no problem I see the rigth data but when I replace Ok() by BadRequest I get the 500 error, same with Postman

Comment: Maybe try changing `Task<ActionResult<MyResponseDto>>` to `Task<IActionResult>`. Or put a try/catch block in your API method to see what exception is being thrown.